# Dataset to sqlite data transfer

Tags: datatable, sqlite, dataset

While development I was in need to create sqlite data base using dataset.

First create empty database file in sqlite. Then using dataset create table and dump data.
Is it possible using some dataset method?

Answer (score 0):

I have done one thing
I have used one query

> select * from sqlite_master where type='table'

That will give me schema of sqllite file from where I want to copy data.

On other end I will execute query return by above query.
That will help to create table dynamically.
On by one I used dataadapter to fill data and assigned dataset datatable data and used
Dataadapter. Update method.